# Use lapply() with as.data.frame() only on top level of nested list

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I have two data frames that share an ID column. The first only has one row per unique ID, the second one has 0, 1 or many rows per ID. I would like to:

1. Left join the first with the second such that instead of creating new rows, a list column is created that contains all rows of the second df as a data frame. Thus the result has the same number of rows as the first df plus this list column filled with data frames.
2. Break up the result of this joining operation by row. Each row should be its own data frame in a list. The will be a nested list because the list column created in step 1. above contains the rows from the second df.

Here is some example data to illustrate the problem.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

first_df <- iris[c(1, 80, 120), ]

second_df <- data.frame(
  Species = c(rep("setosa", 3), rep("versicolor", 1)),
  extra1 = rnorm(4),
  extra2 = rnorm(4)
)
```

```
> print(first_df)
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
80           5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 versicolor
120          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5  virginica

> print(second_df)
     Species     extra1     extra2
1     setosa  0.2389923 -0.7160764
2     setosa  0.5882777 -1.1993319
3     setosa -1.2673999  0.0643962
4 versicolor -1.4064294  1.6996292
```

Step 1. is relatively straightforward. I just nest the second_df on all columns except the id column (in this case "Species").

```
second_df_nested <- second_df %>% 
  nest("second_df" = setdiff(names(second_df), "Species"))
```

```
> print(as_tibble(second_df_nested))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Species    second_df
  <chr>      <list>          
1 setosa     <tibble [3 × 2]>
2 versicolor <tibble [1 × 2]>
```

Then I left_join() normally.

```
final_df_joined <- first_df %>% 
  left_join(second_df_nested, by = join_by(Species))
```

```
> print(as_tibble(final_df_joined))
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    second_df      
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>      <list>          
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa     <tibble [3 × 2]>
2          5.7         2.6          3.5         1   versicolor <tibble [1 × 2]>
3          6           2.2          5           1.5 virginica  <NULL>
```

The step 2., however, is proving quite tricky. Here is what I would like to happen, illustrated using the first_df before joining.

```
> first_df %>% 
+   apply(1, as.list) %>% 
+   lapply(as.data.frame)
$`1`
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa

$`80`
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1          5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 versicolor

$`120`
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1          6.0         2.2          5.0         1.5 virginica
```

As you can see, every row is its own list item and every list item is a data frame with 1 row.

However, when I try to do this with the joined df, it doesn't work. It seems to be that `as.data.frame()` is trying to unnest all lists at the top level and below. But I need it to only convert the level at the top to a data frame.

```
> final_df_joined %>% 
+   apply(1, as.list) %>% 
+   lapply(as.data.frame)
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Is there a way to tell `as.data.frame()` that it should ignore nested data frames below the top level? Or is there perhaps another, better solution to my problem? For context (although I don't think it's relevant to the question): the purpose of these transformations is that I need to convert the data into a specific nested JSON format.

I would greatly appreciate any tips you may have!

Comment: Don't use `apply()`, use `split()`, e.g. something like `split(seq(nrow(.)))`

Comment: I think this did it, thank you so much! So the take-away would be: If I want to "listify" all levels of a nested data frame, I should use `apply(1, as.list)` and if I want to break up only the top level of a data frame into list items I should use `split()`?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use `apply()` at all - apply converts your data frame to a matrix so all data is coerced to a common class.  If you inspect the output of your attempt you'll see all the columns are strings.